# Removing REM INSERTING and SET DEFINE OFF from SQLcl Output

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqlcl

I ran below script to get data from Oracle, and then load to Postgres with psql.

```
SET SQLFORMAT INSERT
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF

SPOOL asset_file.sql
SELECT * FROM FINANCE.ASSET;
SPOOL OFF
QUIT
```

However in SQLcl output, the first few lines are:

```
REM INSERTING into finance.asset
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into finance.asset( ...
```

which results in error because the first two lines not recognized by Postgres, using psql client with -f option.

What are options that I can further put in SQLcl script to ensure those first two lines not being output? I don't want `REM INSERTING` and `SET DEFINE ..` in the output.

Comment: unfortunately they say this is not possible and suggest to search and replace afterwards: [link](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/database-export-and-set-define-off-4946)